# Office 2016's compatibility with 2010

Tags: microsoft-office

Can Office-2016-made files be opened on Office 2010?

Comment: [What type of questions should I avoid asking at superuser ??](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: there should not be an issue between 2010 and 2016. The issue only arises for versions 2003 or lower.